# How to remove comma between taxonomy terms?

Tags: 6, theming, taxonomy-terms

I style my taxonomy terms as boxes, so I don't need comma between them.

Could somebody give me any advice?

Comment: boxes?  can you show an image/example

Comment: I mean similar graphic boxes, similar to question tags on this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice blog post on styling taxonomy in node.tpl.php (or node-contenttype.tpl.php): http://oliverdavies.co.uk/blog/how-style-drupal-6s-taxonomy-lists-php-css-and-jquery

Looks like you should check your node.tpl.php for something like `<?php if ($terms): ?>` and then you might see where the commas are being added and strip them out. This will depend on what theme you are using.