# How to remove chosen comma between taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How can I remove comma from theese ingrediens and let them float left? I am using chosen for my taxonomyes

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the content type's display settings and change the display format.

```
/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display
```

is an example url you might go to to edit the `article` content type display settings.

Comment: And what to do in there? cause it doens't help if I change it to clean text or something like that, the comma is still here?

Comment: ok, if you cannot do it there by changing the display type then it is likely that you need to make code changes to your template file, see: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/how-to-remove-comma-between-taxonomy-terms

Comment: That link in the question is broken :)

Comment: The rest of the answer is still relevant and tells you what you need to do.